# Magento2 : Product Details Page (PDP) Animation images are not showing animation on frontend

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have uploaded a gif image for a product, after uploading it is working in the backend, but When I go to frontend on product details page it is not working I mean it is not showing its animated view.

Comment: have you found solution for this ?

Comment: i am working for the same but not found any solution for this if you have please share it.

Answer (score 0):

It converts it into another gif image.

i.e. if you upload photo.gif it will now be photo_1.gif

Use an FTP Program to upload the original photo.gif, but rename it to photo_1.gif and overwrite the smaller converted file.

The animated gif should work now.

This works on Magento 1.9x for Category images